# Make VS2015 use angular-cli ng at build time in a .NET project

Tags: visual-studio, angular, visual-studio-2015, angular-cli

I open a clearer question.

How is it possible on precompile script in a .NET project, to make VS2015 build the Angular2-cli project with angular-cli tools (`ng`) installed globally via npm.

Steps:
 - `npm install -g angular-cli`
 - In our .NET project under VS2015, on F5 (build) we need `ng build` to be called.

We tried:

```
"precompile": [ "npm install -g angular-cli", "npm install", "ng build --prod" ],
```

But I encounter errors on VS2015 console. Full logs: http://pastebin.com/RMiU6eMe

VS2015 doesn't seem to manage to use globally installed `ng` command.

I tried in our script to call directly the `ng` tool installed locally as declared in our package.json via npm install:

```
"precompile": [ "npm install", "node_modules/angular-cli/bin/ng build --prod" ],
```

But VS2015 answers as below:

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v14.0\DotNet\Microsoft.DotNet.Common.Targets(262,5):
>   error : The specified executable is not a valid application for this
>   OS platform.

I don't want to have to run separately from command line `ng build` (which works by the way...) BEFORE being able to build on VS2015.

Comment: Please note I also tried to create a powershell script, but when powershell script is launched at post-build, VS2015 doesn't wait for the script to be completed and it continues to publish. So my Angular generated files are not "here" when the publish is complete since building our angular app requires some time.

Answer (score 0):

Add a command `"build": "ng build",` in your `package.json`, then, instead of trying to run the ng build, just run the `npm build`.

You can also add this to your package.json to bundling it each time you build your solution.

```
"-vs-binding": { "BeforeBuild": [ "build" ] }
```

Comment: I tried this solution and by doing `npm build` it also gives me the same error as seen here http://pastebin.com/RMiU6eMe