# ASP.NET Core run angular build before docker build

Tags: azure, angular, docker, asp.net-core

We have a basic Docker file which need to build our ASP.NET Core application. Our frontend is an Angular2 one.

In our current process we do:

- `npm run build`: build the angular2 frontend part, which write output
  JS files in `/wwwroot`. These files will be included by ASP.NET Core
  views and controllers.
- Then we `docker build` which build and encapsulate our ASP.NET Core project. We then intend to deploy it anywhere.

Our DockerFile:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]
RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

### Our question

How to add in our dockerfiles steps to:

- Run `npm install` required files for our Angular2 frontend. Our `package.json` file is at ASP.NET project root.
- Run `npm run build:prod`: which build Angular2 project and generated files in wwwroot.

Before running `dotnet build`. We tried to simply try to indicate these commands before `RUN ["dotnet", "build"]` :

```
RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g angular-cli
RUN npm run build:prod
```

but Azure returns an "unexpected Error" without more details.

Comment: Did you tried using the `script` section in project.json (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/project-json#scripts)? There are pre and post compile/processing triggers for it

Comment: Yes i tried it but since we use Angular-cli to build, I encoutered problems with VisualStudio. I opened a question about it but it seems to be a dead end: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41575174/make-vs2015-use-angular-cli-ng-at-build-time-in-a-net-project/41594294#41594294

Comment: I see. Also you may want to consider to use `dotnet publish` instead, this will generate binaries file and put these binaries into your docker container similar to Scott's blog http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringASPNETCoreWithDockerInBothLinuxAndWindowsContainers.aspx. Your current approach also seems to include the source code into the docker container, which I'd personally consider a bad idea to deploy your source code on the servers (in case your server gets compromised).

Comment: Ok i will look into it. I already tried to create a post/prepublish event but it always returns an error in VS2015. But how to add my `npm install` and `npm run build:prod` commands?

Comment: Each entry in the array is one command: `"prepublish": [ "npm install","npm run build:prod" ],` etc. The default project.json already has `npm install` as prepublish step. Not sure how it changes with csproj yet

Comment: I already tried this and I always get the same error: http://pastebin.com/RMiU6eMe . When running form powershell it works but I don't manage to launch a proper powershell from prepublish and make dotnet WAIT for the powershell to complete before going further. Still, will it work inside a docker?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not possible to run npm commands directly from the docker file, the docker engine needs a program like a shell or powershell to execute npm commands. That is the reason the coomand `RUN npm install` in the docker file does not work.

You can try specifying powershell to be used to run npm command

```
RUN powershell -NoProfile -Command RUN npm install
```

I suggest an alternative option as below

In the root of the solution, Create a build script **build.sh** with npm commands, dotnet restore, build, publish and run commands.

```
#!bin/bash
set -e
npm install
npm install -g angular-cli
npm run build:prod
dotnet restore
dotnet test test/WebTests/project.json
dotnet publish src/Web/project.json -c release -o $(pwd)/publish/web
dotnet run
```

Note: 
1.The build.sh above is just a sample, add remove and edit as per your need.

2.Make sure that the file build.sh does not have windows specific line endings otherwise shell will have trouble executing it.

From the root of your solution, open your power shell prompt
Now we can directly use the aspnetcore build image to run the application as below

```
docker run -it --rm -v "$pwd\:/sln" microsoft/aspnetcore-build:1.0.1 sh ./build.sh
```

The option `-v "$pwd\:/sln"` mounts the current directory as /sln directory in the container.

Refer to a very well written MSDN article [Optimized Docker Images](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/stevelasker/2016/09/29/building-optimized-docker-images-with-asp-net-core/)

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy Can i ask, where is `npm` installed in these scripts? It doesn't come with `microsoft/dotnet:latest` right?