# Exclude path at Docker image build time to improve size

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

In our project, we have an ASP.NET Core project with an Angular2 client. At Docker build time, we launch:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest
COPY . /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

RUN apt-get -qq update ; apt-get -qqy --no-install-recommends install \
    git \
    unzip
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_7.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs build-essential
RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

RUN npm install
RUN npm run build:prod

RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run"]
```

Since restoring the npm packages is essential to be able to build the Angular2 client using `npm run build`, our Docker image is HUGE, I mean almost 2GB. Built Angular2 client is only 1.7Mb itself.

Our app does nothing fancy: simple web API writing to MongoDB and displaying static files.

**In order to improve the size of our image, is there any way to exclude path which are useless at run time? For example `node_modules` or any .NET Core source**?

Comment: What is producing your 2 GB? Unlikely the npm alone.

Comment: I guess it is the ASP.NET Core dependencies and runtime. I don't know how to see exactly what is causing this huge size in a Docker image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dotnet may restore much, especially if you have multiple targets platforms (linux, mac, windows).

Depending on how your application is configured (i.e. as portable .NET Core app or as self-contained), it can also pull the whole .NET Core Framework for one, or multiple platforms and/or architectures (x64, x86). This is mainly explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/deploying/).

When `"Microsoft.NETCore.App" : "1.0.0"` is defined, without the type platform, then then complete framework will be fetched via nuget. Then if you have multiple runtimes defined

```
 "runtimes": {
   "win10-x64": {},
   "win10-x86": {},
   "osx.10.10-x86": {},
   "osx.10.10-x64": {}
 }
```

it will get native libraries for all this platforms too. But not only in your project directory but also in `~/.nuget` and `npm-cache` additionally to `node_modules` in your project + eventual copies in your `wwwdata`.

However, this is not how docker works. Everything you execute inside the `Dockerfile` **is written to the virtual filesystem** of the container! That's why you see this issues.

You should follow [my previous comment on your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41617577/asp-net-core-run-angular-build-before-docker-build#comment70436843_41617577):

Run `dotnet restore`, `dotne build` and `dotnet publish` **outside** the Dockerfile, for example in a bash or powershell/batch script.

Once finished call copy the content of the publish folder in your container with

```
dotnet publish
docker build bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish ... (your other parameters here)
```

This will generate publish files on your file system, only containing the required dll files, Views and `wwwroot` content without all the other build files, artifacts, caches or source and will run the docker process from the `bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish` folder.

You also need to change your docker files, to copy the files instead of running the commands you have during container building.

Scott uses this Dockerfile for [his example in his blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ExploringASPNETCoreWithDockerInBothLinuxAndWindowsContainers.aspx):

```
FROM ... # Your base image here
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "YourWebAppName.dll"] # Application to run
ARG source=. # An argument from outside, here store the path from real filesystem
WORKDIR /app
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://+:82 # Define the port it should listen
EXPOSE 82
COPY $source . # copy the files from defined folder, here bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0\publish to inside the docker container
```

This is the recommended approach for building docker containers. When you run the build commands inside, all the build and publish artifacts remain in the virtual file system and the docker image grows unexpectedly.

Comment: I agree with this. You should bake your build tools into the image and share that amongst your developers. The actual building of your software should be performed by a container and the results stored on your local file system.

Comment: Thanks about this explaination. It doesn't solve my VS2015 ng build problem though ;). I think I will create a bash and do all the build stuff from command line on Linux. **My docker is intended to run on a Ubuntu x64 VM**. Do I need to change my runtime in `project.json` to reflect only Linux 64?

Comment: @BlackHoleGalaxy: No, only your `dotnet publish` command, i.e. `dotnet publish --framework netcoreapp1.0 --runtime ubuntu.16.04-x64`. For a full list of valid RIDs (Runtime Identifiers) see http://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/rid-catalog, where the runtime also needs to be specified in project.json (or *.csproj's `<RuntimeIdentifiers>`)

Comment: I mean of course your `runtime` in project.json must contain all target platforms (it is important for nuget to restore the correct packages) that you want to possibly deploy for, but you probably have this already or you wouldn't be able to run it under Linux at all